Using SPI3 for Waveshare 2-CH CAN FD HAT
I'm using a CM4 on the IO Board, the Hat is connected with wires going to GPIO8-11 (SPI0), GPIO0-3 (SPI3), and GPIO 12 and 13 for interrupts. However it doesn't appear that the device tree supports this  configuration: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-6.6.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/mcp251xfd-overlay.dts
So I've tried to modify the mcp2518fd overlay, but only got SPI0 to work. Is it even possible to use SPI3 in this configuration?
Modified device-tree:
/*force_eeprom_read=0
disable_poe_fan=1

 * Device tree overlay for mcp251x/mcp2518fd on spi0.0
 */

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2836", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";
    /* disable spi-dev for spi0.0 */

    fragment@0{
        target = <&spidev0>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };

    /*fragment@1{
        target = <&spidev3>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };*/

    /* the interrupt pin of the can-controller */
    fragment@1 {
        target = <&gpio>;
        __overlay__ {
            can_int_pins: can_int_pins {
                brcm,pins = <12 13>;
                brcm,function = <0 0>; /* input */
            };
            spi3_pins: spi3_pins {
                        brcm,pins = <1 2 3>;
                        brcm,function = <7 7 7>; /* alt4 */
            };

           spi3_cs_pins: spi3_cs_pins {
                        brcm,pins = <0>;
                        brcm,function = <7>; /* output */
            };

        };
    };

    /* the clock/oscillator of the can-controller */
    fragment@2 {
        target-path = "/clocks";
        __overlay__ {
            /* external 40M oscillator of mcp2518fd on SPI0.0 */
            mcp251xfd_osc: mcp251xfd_osc {
                compatible = "fixed-clock";
                #clock-cells = <0>;
              clock-frequency  = <40000000>;
            };
        };
    };

    /* the spi config of the can-controller itself binding everything together */
    fragment@3 {
        target = <&spi0>;
        __overlay__ {
            /* needed to avoid dtc warning */
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

          status = "okay";
            can0: can@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&can_int_pins>;
                compatible = "microchip,mcp251xfd";
                spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                interrupts = <12 8>; /* IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW */
                clocks = <&mcp251xfd_osc>;
            };

        };
    };
    /* the spi config of the can-controller itself binding everything together */
    fragment@4 {
        target = <&spi3>;
        __overlay__ {
            /* needed to avoid dtc warning */
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            cs-gpios = <&gpio 0 7>;
            status = "okay";
            can1: can@1 {
                reg = <0>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&spi3_pins &spi3_cs_pins>;
                compatible = "microchip,mcp251xfd";
                spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                interrupts = <13 8>; /* IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW */
                clocks = <&mcp251xfd_osc>;
            };
        };
    };
};

